# External CSS to style VML

Tags: internet-explorer, raphael, vml

is it possible to use external CSS file to style properties such as fill or stroke colour of VML objects? By the way, I'm using Raphael to create my VML shapes for IE.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some sample code of your markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the *id* attribute of the given node with RaphaelJS...

```
var c = paper.circle(10, 10, 10);
c.node.id = 'azerty';
```

...and style it with CSS:

```
#azerty {/* write your CSS formatting here */}
```

I think you could do the same thing with the *class* attribute instead of *id* (to be verified). You would then use the *.className* JavaScript property.